# how to avoid (or handle) http 429 programmatically

Tags: javascript, image, http-status-code-429

I have a page with a lot of `<img>` tags (I am assembling this page programmatically). Inevitably some of the requests for image encounter http 429. Thankfully, the remote server sends a bunch of helpful response headers as follows

```
HTTP/1.1 429 TOO MANY REQUESTS
X-RateLimit-Limit: 20
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 20
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1646307858.32
Retry-After: 1
```

I am wondering if I could somehow wrap my `<img>` tags in code that catches the http `response.status` and then uses the above headers (for example, the `Retry-After` header) to ask for the failed image again after a set delay.

Logically, it seems to me the above would work, but I can't figure out how to code this. Fwiw, this is a completely client-side web page.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: You *might* be able to detect the type of failure if the images (a) come from the same origin or (b) the origin of the images also sends CORS headers. I'd start by implementing something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#element.onerror) and inspecting the event that is sent to see if there is anything in it that can discern the kind of error that happened.

Comment: thanks, this looks promising but it didn't really work for me (using `<img src="${uri}" onerror="this.onerror=null;setTimeout(() => { this.src='${uri}' },1000);">`). My guess is that perhaps http 429 doesn't seem like an error. It is, after all, a valid response, just not an image

Comment: I may be wrong… tested it again and it seems to work. I will test more and come back and report

Comment: do you know a solution for python? My problem is:[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75110778/http-errors-on-chrome-while-instagram-scrapping?noredirect=1#comment132547047_75110778

Comment: do you know a solution for python my problem is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75110778/http-errors-on-chrome-while-instagram-scrapping?noredirect=1#comment132547047_75110778

Comment: @freeengineer sorry, I am not a Python programmer. But the logic is simple to implement. Query for the image, and if there is a 429 error, wait for a second or two (1000 or 2000 ms) and query again

Answer (score 1):

You cannot easily get at image headers on the client.

It is not possible to use a simple onload/onerror handler to look at retry-after headers. To access headers, you need something like a server proxy that uses cURL and examines the headers after getting a 429

If you just want to try again after error, you can try something like this

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll("img[data-src]");
  let cnt = 0;

  const loadImage = src => {
    let img = new Image();
    let tgtImage = images[cnt];
    img.addEventListener("load", function() {
      tgtImage.src = this.src
    })
    img.addEventListener("error", function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        loadImage(`${src}`)
      }, 1000)
    })
    img.src = src;
    cnt++
    if (cnt >= images.length) return;
    loadImage(images[cnt].dataset.src)
  }
  loadImage(images[cnt].dataset.src)
})
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x300&text=placeholder" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/200x300&text=image1" />
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x300&text=placeholder" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/200x300&text=image2" />
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x300&text=placeholder" data-src="https://ERROR.com/200x300&text=image3" />
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x300&text=placeholder" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/200x300&text=image4" />
```

Comment: thanks. I am not quite sure where to use your suggested workaround. As I mentioned, my page is really a bunch of image tags `<img src="${uri}">`. As I noted in a comment above, I tried using `setTimeout()` in `onerror` but that didn't work. I am wondering if using a Promise and then catching the `response.status` is the solution

Comment: See updated example

Comment: This solution doesn't apply the `Retry-After` header as @punkish is mentioning.  I'm also looking into a solution for this.

Comment: @heyitsalec OP did not need the retry-after afterall. It is not possible to use a simple onload/onerror handler to look at retry-after headers. To do what you want, you need something like a server proxy that uses cURL and examines the headers after getting a 429

Answer (score 0):

the following worked for me

```
<img 
   src="${uri}" 
   onerror="this.onerror=null; setTimeout(() => { this.src='${uri}' },1000);">
```

thanks [@spender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14357/spender) for the hint. Thanks also to [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) for an alternative solution that is useful to know even if it is not for me at this point.